# Is there a way to get the protocol in Connect/Express 3

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

Is there a way to get the protocol (http|https) in Express?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`req.protocol`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.protocol):

```
app.get('/protocol', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.protocol);
});
```

Though, you may also need to [`enable`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.enable) [`trust proxy`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings) for your application:

```
app.configure('production', function () {
    app.enable('trust proxy');
});
```

Comment: `app.enable('trust proxy');
app.get('trust proxy');// => true console.log(req.procotol) => undefined` That didn't seem to work

Comment: @jwerre That likely because I had it as `procotol` rather than `protocol`. :) Sorry.

Comment: Ha!! Copy & Paste stikes again